# Open the first file in a folder using command prompt

Tags: command-prompt, filemaker, getfiles

I am trying to get the name of the first file of a folder using command prompt command. The first files' names in these folders do not follow any rules unfortunately. They are also different types so there isn't an extension rule. My final goal is to pass this name into FileMaker so that I can get all the files that are inside these folders.

In addition, if there is a way to take the name by just using a script step or a function in Filemaker, that would also be perfect!

Thank you so much!

P/s: I'm sorry for not being clear before, I'm trying to perform this on a Windows machine

Comment: Hi! I'm using Windows. Yep, it is decided by per date creation/modified!

Comment: What have you done so far? Is the question on how to trigger cmd from FIleMaker, how to get the result back or do you need cmd statement?

Comment: I guess the general question is how to get a file name, preferred, the first one according to date creation/modified that is inside a given folder.

Comment: Still unclear. If you need to sort your files by date and time use dir /o:d. Getting cmd to return a single file will need a batch script. It is easier to return the list to FileMaker and get the first value with getValue().

Comment: so how exactly to get the list to FileMaker? I'm new to FileMaker so I'm trying to figure out how to do things. Thank you

Comment: I posted a full description as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run cmd from FileMaker use "Send Event" script step in your FileMaker script, "Send the" dropdown should be set to "open document/application" and select "Text" option. In text box enter

```
cmd.exe /c "your cmd command"
```

e.g.

```
cmd.exe /c MKDIR "C:\Users\Nicolai\Desktop\ImportantStuff"
```

You have a few options to get the output back.

1. Save the output of CMD to a text file and import it into FileMaker as text file
2. Save the output as XML and import it as XML
3. Save the output as HTML, load it in FileMaker webviewer and scrap the context of webviewer
4. Copy the output of cmd command and paste it into a FileMaker field with "Go to Field" / "Paste" script steps

The last one is the easiest to implement, but has a disadvantage of overwriting user clipboard. I am using clip command on Windows 10. I am not sure if it was available on the earlier Windows systems.

My "Send Event" looks like this:

```
cmd.exe /c DIR "C:\Users\Nicolai\Desktop\MyFolder" /o:d /b | clip
```

I pasted the result into a myField field:

```
GetValue ( myTestDb::myField; 1)
```

Gives me the first file name sorted by date and time

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps a lot for a beginner like me!

Comment: You are welcome and please flag the answer as answered if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

In case (hopefully) you are using linux do:

```
ls | sort -n | head -1
```

Comment: even on *nix [it's a bad idea to pipe `ls` like that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get the name of the first file of a folder using command prompt command. The first files' names in these folders do not follow any rules unfortunately.

Get the first file based on what criteria: date created, file name ascending, file type?

If you want to import photos or text files from a folder, the Import Records script step will do this.

Comment: Hi! From date created is what I meant, sorry for the unclear question. I would need the file name so I can pass it in as a variable.